# PyQt4.QtCore runtime-error: how to downgrade sip/API?

Tags: python, python-2.7, runtime-error, pyqt4

I am trying to run a legacy python 2 code from 2011 (written by another person). I installed the required old libraries with anaconda in a python 2.7 environment. It needs PyQt4. I'm on Linux (Fedora 32). When trying to run the code I get this messasge:

RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v11.0 to v11.3 but the PyQt4.QtCore module requires API v8.1

All online help that I've found goes for upgrading to a newer version of sip/API. In this case it seems that I need to downgrade. Please, any indication on how to do that and get this old piece of code working?

Thank you

Comment: How complex is the program? Because it's possible that it could be easier to port it to PyQt5 than trying to "restore" an environment that old

Comment: It is somewhat complex, it calls 19 sub-scripts and I don't understand yet completely how they are related. The person that wrote it says he doesn't have time to update it. So it seems that I will have to port it in the end. Thanks.

Comment: If the program doesn't use too complex implementations/hacks/customization, the port is probably going to be pretty straightforward. The base change is that the QtGui module has been splitted into QtGui and QtWidgets, if that project uses wildcard imports (`from PyQt4.QtGui import *`) then you're lucky as you only need to add the QtWidgets module. Otherwise do some research on the topic in order to find what classes belong to what (usually, everything *directly* widget-related is on QtWidgets, other things such as fonts and painting is not), as there are some tutorials about it, even for PyQt.